# How to vectorise a function

Tags: r

I have a function that takes some free text and then divides the text into columns based on a list of words. It works fine but it has been suggested to me that it would work better if it was vectorised.

The function is called `Extractor`:

```
Extractor <- function(x, y, stra, strb, t) {
  x <- data.frame(x)
  t <- gsub("[^[:alnum:],]", " ", t)
  t <- gsub(" ", "", t, fixed = TRUE)
  x[, t] <-
    stringr::str_extract(x[, y], stringr::regex(paste(stra,
                                                      "(.*)", strb, sep = ""), 
                                                dotall = TRUE))
  x[, t] <- gsub("\\\\.*", "", x[, t])

  names(x[, t]) <- gsub(".", "", names(x[, t]), fixed = TRUE)
  x[, t] <- gsub("       ", "", x[, t])
  x[, t] <- gsub(stra, "", x[, t], fixed = TRUE)
  if (strb != "") {
    x[, t] <- gsub(strb, "", x[, t], fixed = TRUE)
  }
  x[, t] <- gsub("       ", "", x[, t])
  x[, t] <- ColumnCleanUp(x, t)
  return(x)
}

ColumnCleanUp <- function(x, y) {
  x <- (data.frame(x))
  x[, y] <- gsub("^\\.\n", "", x[, y])
  x[, y] <- gsub("^:", "", x[, y])
  x[, y] <- gsub(".", "\n", x[, y], fixed = TRUE)
  x[, y] <- gsub("\\s{5}", "", x[, y])
  x[, y] <- gsub("^\\.", "", x[, y])
  x[, y] <- gsub("$\\.", "", x[, y])
  return(x[, y])
}
```

and I use it as follows:

```
HistolTree<-list("Hospital Number","Patient Name","DOB:","General Practitioner:",
"Date of Procedure:","Clinical Details:","Macroscopic description:","Histology:","Diagnosis:","")
for(i in 1:(length(HistolTree)-1)) {
Mypath<-Extractor(Mypath,"PathReportWhole",as.character(HistolTree[i]),
as.character(HistolTree[i+1]),as.character(HistolTree[i]))
}
```

An example input text is:

```
Mypath<-"Hospital Number 233456 Patient Name: Jonny Begood
DOB: 13/01/77 General Practitioner: Dr De'ath Date of Procedure: 13/01/99 Clinical Details: Dyaphagia and reflux Macroscopic description: 3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies. Histology: These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs. Diagnosis: Acid reflux likely"
Mypath<-data.frame(Mypath)
names(Mypath)<-"PathReportWhole"
```

The expected output is:

```
structure(list(PathReportWhole = structure(1L, .Label = "Hospital Number 233456 Patient Name: Jonny Begood\n    DOB: 13/01/77 General Practitioner: Dr De'ath Date of Procedure: 13/01/99 Clinical Details: Dyaphagia and reflux Macroscopic description: 3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies. Histology: These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs. Diagnosis: Acid reflux likely", class = "factor"), 
    HospitalNumber = " 233456 ", PatientName = " Jonny Begood", 
    DOB = " 13/01/77 ", GeneralPractitioner = NA_character_, 
    Dateofprocedure = NA_character_, ClinicalDetails = " Dyaphagia and reflux ", 
    Macroscopicdescription = " 3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies\n ", 
    Histology = " These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs\n ", 
    Diagnosis = " Acid reflux likely"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), .Names = c("PathReportWhole", "HospitalNumber", "PatientName", 
"DOB", "GeneralPractitioner", "Dateofprocedure", "ClinicalDetails", 
"Macroscopicdescription", "Histology", "Diagnosis"), class = "data.frame")
```

Basically, I call the function recurrently through a loop (although only one example here, the actual dataframe has >2000 rows).

Is `apply()` a way of applying the function in a vectorised way? If not can I have a pointer on how to vectorise this so I can avoid the use of a loop? I understand that the idea of vectorising the function means applying the function to a vector as a whole instead of looping and that I need to convert the input list into a character vector but I am stuck from there on.

Comment: What is the function `ColumnCleanup()`? We'll need that in order to run your code.

Comment: @StuartAllen the function for ColumnCleanUp has been added as above. Thanks

Comment: There are many thinks which could be improved here. First of all, why does your `Extractor` function take the same argument twice? In your loop, your function call seems to take `as.character(HistolTree[i])` for both arguments `stra` and `t`. I would rewrite the function in a way that you only provide dataframe and one vector of strings (the content of `HistolTree`), and uses this vector by itself.

Comment: Also, why are there two lines of code to reformat the argument `t`, which you provide yourself? Why not provide it in the correct way when calling the function?

Comment: Appears that you are attempting to parse data that are delivered as key-value pairs. Life would be much simpler if you put some honest-to-Chrismas delimiters to separate the key-value pairs. There are quite a few SO questions and answers with code that handles this kind of input.

Comment: You also spell Date of Procedure differently in the HistolTree and MyPath variables.

Comment: If you're not too set on approaching as you did so far, I had a shot at it (although half-guessing what you want). It is [here](https://gist.github.com/meriops/90a33ef0d06fc0ed62779895bd70e722) for now. See if that  helps (maybe with a few tweaks), if so, I can make it into a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than vectorise your existing function I thought I'd try to simplify your various regular expressions somewhat. I can see what it is you are doing, you have a data.frame with raw pathology data in a nasty looking single string, such as:

> Hospital Number 233456 Patient Name: Jonny Begood DOB: 13/01/77
>   General Practitioner: Dr De'ath Date of Procedure: 13/01/99 Clinical
>   Details: Dyaphagia and reflux Macroscopic description: 3 pieces of
>   oesophagus, all good biopsies. Histology: These show chronic reflux
>   and other bits n bobs. Diagnosis: Acid reflux likely

You are using a good approach I believe, which is to use the headers ("Hospital Number", "Patient Name:", ...) in order to extract the data ("233456", "Jonny Begood", ...). I think, however, there is a simpler way to do this with regular expressions, namely to use the headers as [lookbehind and lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  tokens. So in the above string we see that the data for *Hospital Number* is everything in between "Hospital Number" and "Patient Name:", with whitespace removed, i.e. "233456". The same principle can be applied to extract each subsequent piece of data. A few more lines of code will get the separate pieces of data into their own columns in the data.frame.

Here's your code to create the test data.frame:

```
Mypath<-"Hospital Number 233456 Patient Name: Jonny Begood DOB: 13/01/77 General Practitioner: Dr De'ath Date of Procedure: 13/01/99 Clinical Details: Dyaphagia and reflux Macroscopic description: 3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies. Histology: These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs. Diagnosis: Acid reflux likely"
Mypath<-data.frame(Mypath)
names(Mypath)<-"PathReportWhole"
```

We then create a character vector of the headers:

```
x <- c("Hospital Number", "Patient Name:", "DOB:", "General Practitioner:", "Date of Procedure:", "Clinical Details:", "Macroscopic description:", "Histology:", "Diagnosis:")
```

Note that these must match *exactly* with the headers contained in the data. Also, we do not need an empty string as the last entry, as you had above.

We can then write a function which takes as parameters the data.frame `df`, the name of the data.frame column containing the raw data `colName` (in order to make the function as general as possible), and the vector of headers `headers`.

```
extractPath <- function(df, colName, headers) {
  # df: data.frame containing raw path data
  # colName: name of column containing data
  # headers: character vector of headers (delimiters in raw path data)

  for (i in seq_len(length(headers))) {

    # left delimiter
    delimLeft <- headers[i]

    # right delimiter, not relevant if at end of headers
    if (i < length(headers)) {
      delimRight <- headers[i+1]
      # regex to match everything between delimiting headers
      regex <- paste0("(?<=", delimLeft, ").*(?=", delimRight, ")")
    } else {
      # regex to match everything to right of final delimiting header
      regex <- paste0("(?<=", delimLeft, ").*$")
    }

    # generate column name for new column
    # use alpha characters only (i.e. ignore colon), and remove spaces
    columnName <- str_extract(delimLeft, "[[:alpha:] ]*") %>% str_replace_all(" ", "")

    # create new column of data, and trim whitespace
    df[[columnName]] <- str_extract(df[[colName]], regex) %>% str_trim()
  }

  # return output data.frame
  df
}
```

Here I'm using the `tidverse` package ecosystem, namely `dplyr` and `stringr`. The function loops through each of the headers, generates appropriate regular expressions, then applies these to create a new column of data.

Call the function thus:

```
out <- extractPath(Mypath, "PathReportWhole", x)
```

And here's the output for the single row test data.frame:

```
> glimpse(out)
Observations: 1
Variables: 10
$ PathReportWhole        <fctr> Hospital Number 233456 Patient Name: Jonny Begood DOB: 13/01/77 General Practitioner: Dr De'ath Date of Procedure: 13/01/99 Clinical Details: Dyaphagia and re...
$ HospitalNumber         <chr> "233456"
$ PatientName            <chr> "Jonny Begood"
$ DOB                    <chr> "13/01/77"
$ GeneralPractitioner    <chr> "Dr De'ath"
$ DateofProcedure        <chr> "13/01/99"
$ ClinicalDetails        <chr> "Dyaphagia and reflux"
$ Macroscopicdescription <chr> "3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies."
$ Histology              <chr> "These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs."
$ Diagnosis              <chr> "Acid reflux likely"
```

(You may want to further tidy the data, convert character dates, and so on.)

I also tested this with a data.frame of several thousand rows and it ran in a second or so.